# Heroku PG Database migration defaulting to production when NODE_ENV is set to staging

Tags: postgresql, heroku, knex.js, heroku-postgres

My app uses Express, Knex and PG library. I have set up my `NODE_ENV` in Heroku to staging using the command `https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#runtime-behavior` ([source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#runtime-behavior)):

```
Setting NODE_ENV and restarting    
NODE_ENV: staging
```

I have a staging env in knexfile:

```js
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
    test: {
        client: 'pg',
        connection: process.env.DB_URL_TEST,
        migrations: {
            directory: './db/migrations',
        },
        seeds: {
            directory: './db/seeds/dev',
        },
        useNullAsDefault: true,
    },
    development: {
        client: 'pg',
        connection: process.env.DB_URL,
        migrations: {
            directory: './db/migrations',
        },
        seeds: {
            directory: './db/seeds/dev',
        },
        useNullAsDefault: true,
    },

    staging: {
        client: 'pg',
        connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        migrations: {
            directory: './db/migrations',
        },
        seeds: {
            directory: './db/seeds/dev',
        },
        useNullAsDefault: true,
    },

    production: {
        client: 'pg',
        connection: process.env.DB_URL_PRODUCTION,
        migrations: {
            directory: './db/migrations',
        },
        seeds: {
            directory: './db/seeds/production',
        },
        useNullAsDefault: true,
    },
};
```

My db config file listens to `NODE_ENV`:

```js
    const knex = require('knex');
const config = require('../knexfile');

const dbEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV;

module.exports = knex(config[dbEnv]);
```

No other config var in Heroku:

[image]

When I run a heroku migration it keeps on defaulting to production env:

```
Running knex migrate:latest
Using environment: production
```

The only way I have found to force the migration into staging env is to set `NODE_ENV` to staging as a Heroku env variable explicitly. I don't understand why staging env is not picked up when running the migration.

**edit**: converted 1st and 3rd screenshot to text. Can't really change the other, it is just a screenshot of a portion of Heroku env variables.

** edit 2**: added the command to set NODE_ENV to staging

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: "I have set up my NODE_ENV in Heroku to staging"—how, exactly?

Comment: @Chris thanks, edited the original post removing couple of screenshots. I have set up my 3 dev environments: local in my machine, staging in Heroku and production in Heroku. Each has a PG DB: local and the 2 last Heroku PG, hence why I want to distinguish between both env in Heroku. Open to ideas if you think this is not optimal

Comment: Thanks for updating your question, but you still haven't answered my question: how did you set `NODE_ENV` to staging?

Comment: @Chris 'heroku config:set NODE_ENV=staging' source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#runtime-behavior , I edited the question adding the command there too

Comment: But `NODE_ENV` isn't shown in the screenshot you provided. Do you see it there?

Comment: @Chris That's the thing, NODE_ENV comes set by default as 'production' from Heroku without having to set the env variable in Heroku explicitely (https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/688). If I change NODE_ENV to 'staging' with the command 'heroku config:set NODE_ENV=staging' I continue to expect not having to set it up explicitely but come as 'staging' and not 'production' anymore

Comment: What do you mean by "If I change NODE_ENV to 'staging' with the command 'heroku config:set NODE_ENV=staging' I continue to expect not having to set it up explicitely"?

Comment: 'heroku config:set NODE_ENV=staging' sets NODE_ENV to 'staging'. Therefore, I expect NODE_ENV to default to 'staging' and not 'production' (https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/688). As stated in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#runtime-behavior, I can set NODE_ENV to any arbitrary string. However, it seems to continue to come back as 'production'. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm still not clear that the value is even being set properly. _Do you see it in your list of config vars?_ If not, it's not being set correctly. Maybe you have multiple apps and are setting it on the wrong one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210530/discussion-between-pere-and-chris).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chatted with Heroku customer support, find below their answer which solved my issue:

> This doesn't come from NODE_ENV but from a side-effect of setting
>   NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true. Refer this article for details.
>
> Set to true to run in "production" mode.
>
> devDependencies are not installed at the topmost level when running
>   local npm install without any arguments. Set the NODE_ENV="production"
>   for lifecycle scripts. This behavior is non-intuitive, so we try to
>   warn about it in the build log:
>
> -----> Creating runtime environment
>
> ```
>    NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
>    NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
>    NODE_VERBOSE=false
>    NODE_ENV=staging
>    NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
>
>    npm scripts will see NODE_ENV=production (not 'staging')
>    https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#production The functionality of user-env-compile is now built into the standard build process.
> ```
>
> NODE_ENV is not set by default on Heroku. What you're seeing is the
>   result of NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION during build. That is true by default
>   during builds (it dramatically speeds them up by not installing
>   devDependencies). Npm sets NODE_ENV to production whenever
>   NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION is true:
>
> -----> Node.js app detected
>
> -----> Reading application state
>          package.json...
>          build directory...
>          cache directory...
>          environment variables...
>
> ```
>    Node engine:         0.10.x
>    Npm engine:          unspecified
>    Start mechanism:     Procfile
>    node_modules source: package.json
>    node_modules cached: true
>
>    NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
>    NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true If you'd like to disable production mode for npm, you can set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION to false using the
> ```
>
> command heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false -a 
>   This will prevent npm from overriding NODE_ENV.